# Rake db:migrate catch errors

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-migration

I have synchronized my development database with my production database, and now there seems to be a lot of migrations that have been applied to this database, but rake doesn't know this. There are quite a few, and there are some in between that have **not** been applied as well.

So everytime I `rake db:migrate` a few migrations are run and then it stops at a "Table already exists" or "Column already exists"

Is there a way to tell rake what is going on, or even better, a argument that I can pass to `rake db:migrate` to tell it to ignore "already exists" errors and just move the hell on.

Comment: Why don't you just specify a version number to migrate only the required?

Comment: My version number is correct in schema.rb. The problem is somehow, un-applied migrations are mixed in between applied migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a `force: true` argument on `create_table` to force it to drop the table and recreate it which usually gets round these errors. However, that seems like a bit of a brute force way to solve the problem.

The problem usually occurs when you dump the schema from production and load it locally. The production schema doesn't know anything about new tables locally and it copies the entire list of `schema_migrations` so the fact that you've run a migration locally is lost.

One way to get round this problem is to skip the `schema_migrations` table from the dump. You'll still get all your production data loaded locally but you won't overwrite your local list of migrations.

With mysqldump it's a question of adding a `--ignore-table=schema_migrations` parameter.

However, you need to be careful with any way that you solve this problem. It's very easy to skip a migration because it creates a table and forget that it also adds a column to an existing table.

I generally prefer a manual approach and either add the values to `schema_migrations` for the migrations I know have happened locally. Or just comment out the bits of a migration that are causing problems whilst I rerun them locally. Neither is particularly nice but I know I haven't missed any steps locally that way.

Comment: where do you add the `--ignore-table=schema_migrations` parameter?

Comment: Something like: `mysqldump -u the_user -p the_database --ignore-table=schema_migrations > the_output.sql`